# Combined Flowables which use throttleLast are stuck for no good reason

Tags: java, rx-java2

After a combineLatest my Flowable chain just did not continue running. Eventually, I tried to reproduce the behavior in a separate class. What I found is a little bit disturbing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    test();
    test();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}

private static void test() {
    System.out.println("before");
    Flowable<Integer> fa = Flowable.<Integer>generate(emitter -> emitter.onNext(1)).observeOn(Schedulers.computation()).throttleLast(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
    Flowable<Integer> fb = Flowable.<Integer>generate(emitter -> emitter.onNext(2)).observeOn(Schedulers.computation()).throttleLast(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
    Flowable.combineLatest(fa, fb, (a, b) -> a - b)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .subscribe(c -> {
                System.out.println("c: " + c);
            });
    System.out.println("after");
}
```

After twice before/after, nothing happens anymore. However, if I comment out one of the two test() calls, it just works. If I replace Schedulers.computation() with Schedulers.io(), it works with both test() calls.

I guess the explanation must be related with the fact that there is one computation thread per core. Even then this behavior does not make any sense to me.

Can anybody enlighten me? Using Schedulers.io() does not seem to be a good solution. By the way, I use throttleLast because the consumer has to be able to control the throughput.

Comment: This is very interesting: it looks simple, but works in non-deterministic way.

Answer (score 1):

I do not exactly understand your issue. I tried the following changing your code a bit:

```
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.google.common.collect.Sets;

import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class TestRxJava2 {

    static final Queue<Integer> fa1 = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>();
    static final Queue<Integer> fb1 = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>();
    static final Queue<Integer> c1 = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>();
    static final Queue<Integer> fa2 = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>();
    static final Queue<Integer> fb2 = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>();
    static final Queue<Integer> c2 = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Flowable<Integer> f1 = test(1);
        Flowable<Integer> f2 = test(2);

        Flowable.zip(f1, f2, (a,b) -> a)
            .blockingSubscribe();

        System.out.println(fa1.size() == 10 && fa1.size() == fa2.size());
        System.out.println(fb1.size() == 10 && fb1.size() == fb2.size());
        System.out.println(c1.size() == 19 && c1.size() == c2.size());

        System.out.println(Sets.difference(Sets.newHashSet(fa1), Sets.newHashSet(fa2)).size() == 0);
        System.out.println(Sets.difference(Sets.newHashSet(fb1), Sets.newHashSet(fb2)).size() == 0);
        System.out.println(Sets.difference(Sets.newHashSet(c1), Sets.newHashSet(c2)).size() == 0);

    }

    private static Flowable<Integer> test(int i) {

        Flowable<Integer> fa = Flowable.<Integer>generate(emitter -> emitter.onNext(1))
                .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .throttleLast(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .take(10)
                .scan((a, b) -> a + b)
                .doOnNext(next -> {
                    if (i == 1) {
                        fa1.add(next);
                    } else {
                        fa2.add(next);
                    }
                });

        Flowable<Integer> fb = Flowable.<Integer>generate(emitter -> emitter.onNext(1))
                .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .throttleLast(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .take(10)
                .scan((a, b) -> a + b)
                .doOnNext(next -> {
                    if (i == 1) {
                        fb1.add(next);
                    } else {
                        fb2.add(next);
                    }
                });

        return Flowable.combineLatest(fa, fb, (a, b) -> a + b)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .doOnNext(next -> {
                    if (i == 1) {
                        c1.add(next);
                    } else {
                        c2.add(next);
                    }
                })
                .doOnNext(next -> System.out.println(i + "CombineLatest : " + next))
                .doOnSubscribe(sb -> System.out.println(i + " subscribed"))
                ;
    }
}
```

Console output as follows:

```
1 subscribed
2 subscribed
1CombineLatest : 2
2CombineLatest : 2
1CombineLatest : 3
2CombineLatest : 3
1CombineLatest : 4
2CombineLatest : 4
1CombineLatest : 5
2CombineLatest : 5
1CombineLatest : 6
2CombineLatest : 6
1CombineLatest : 7
2CombineLatest : 7
1CombineLatest : 8
2CombineLatest : 8
1CombineLatest : 9
2CombineLatest : 9
1CombineLatest : 10
2CombineLatest : 10
1CombineLatest : 11
2CombineLatest : 11
1CombineLatest : 12
2CombineLatest : 12
1CombineLatest : 13
2CombineLatest : 13
1CombineLatest : 14
2CombineLatest : 14
1CombineLatest : 15
2CombineLatest : 15
1CombineLatest : 16
2CombineLatest : 16
1CombineLatest : 17
2CombineLatest : 17
1CombineLatest : 18
2CombineLatest : 18
1CombineLatest : 19
2CombineLatest : 19
1CombineLatest : 20
2CombineLatest : 20
true
true
true
true
true
true
```

Could you explain in terms of this code, what is exactly your issue?

Comment: How many cores does your computer have? I get a different output. 37 instead of 46 lines. At the end:

true
true
false
true
true
true

Can you test what happens if you call test() a few more times?

Comment: I have 4 cores, 8 threads. I tried running three times and indeed i do not get the same result!

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. Looks like this particular tight-loop setup won't let the `throttleLast`s have the opportunity to emit. I've run your code several times on my 4 core machine and occasionally I get the `-1`s printed out.

You could use some other `Scheduler` for the `throttleLast` such as `Schedulers.single()` so the `computation()` `Scheduler` is freed up a bit. However, the underlying problem is the tight-loop which can peg down a thread in the `computation` `Scheduler` so if the very same thread is assigned to another tight-loop work, it may not execute within a reasonable time.

By adding some `doOnNext` and `doOnSubscribe` calls, it seems that most of the time test-1's `fa` and test-2's `fb` is emitting data but not the `test-1-fb` and `test-2-fa` respectively, thus `combineLatest` doesn't produce any values due to lack of pairing.

**Edit**

One of the properties playing into the issue is that `observeOn` is optimized for sustained streaming between a generator thread and the emission thread chosen, which in certain circumstances may peg down both threads. It is also possible to switch between threads in a more thread-use friendly manner by turning each source emission and earch request into its own task and relying on the underlying thread pool's fairness. The following custom operator should unblock your use case. Replace both `observeOn(Schedulers.computation())` with `compose(requestObserveOn(Schedulers.computation()))`.

```
static <T> FlowableTransformer<T, T> requestObserveOn(Scheduler scheduler) {
    return f -> new RequestObserveOn<>(f, scheduler);
}

static final class RequestObserveOn<T> extends Flowable<T> {

    final Flowable<T> source;

    final Scheduler scheduler;

    RequestObserveOn(Flowable<T> source, Scheduler scheduler) {
        this.source = source;
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    @Override
    protected void subscribeActual(Subscriber<? super T> s) {
        source.subscribe(new RequestObserveOnSubscriber<>(s, scheduler.createWorker()));
    }

    static final class RequestObserveOnSubscriber<T> 
    extends AtomicLong
    implements FlowableSubscriber<T>, Subscription, Runnable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3167152788131496136L;

        final Subscriber<? super T> actual;

        final Worker worker;

        final Runnable requestOne;

        Subscription upstream;

        volatile T item;
        Throwable error;
        volatile boolean done;

        long emitted;
        boolean terminated;

        RequestObserveOnSubscriber(Subscriber<? super T> actual,
                Scheduler.Worker worker) {
            this.actual = actual;
            this.worker = worker;
            this.requestOne = () -> upstream.request(1L);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
            upstream = s;
            actual.onSubscribe(this);
            worker.schedule(requestOne);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(T t) {
            item = t;
            worker.schedule(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            error = t;
            done = true;
            worker.schedule(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            done = true;
            worker.schedule(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (terminated) {
                return;
            }
            for (;;) {
                boolean d = done;
                T v = item;
                boolean empty = v == null;

                if (d && empty) {
                    Throwable ex = error;
                    if (ex != null) {
                        actual.onError(ex);
                    } else {
                        actual.onComplete();
                    }
                    worker.dispose();
                    terminated = true;
                    return;
                }
                long e = emitted;
                if (!empty && e != get()) {
                    item = null;
                    actual.onNext(v);
                    emitted = e + 1;
                    worker.schedule(requestOne);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void request(long n) {
            BackpressureHelper.add(this, n);
            worker.schedule(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void cancel() {
            upstream.cancel();
            worker.dispose();
            item = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any documentation about the tight-loop which I could read to better understand the problem? Do you agree that this qualifies as a bug?

Comment: Just using `.throttleFirst(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.single())` does not seem to solve the problem.

Comment: There is no documentation because this is an usage corner case: you have the same number of fast generating sources that don't give up their respective threads and any other work to be done by those threads have little to no chance to run. This is not a bug but a somewhat obscure property of `observeOn` and how `Scheduler`s are assigned. Try also removing the `subscribeOn`.

Comment: Posted an update to the answer that contains a custom operator to workaround your use case.

Comment: Removing `subscribeOn` helps. However, I do not understand why. Also, I appreciate your help, but I really do not think that this should require a custom solution. In my opinion, this is something which should just work.